# How to force mstest result to overide the results file when running the test from command-line

Tags: unit-testing, command-line, mstest

I want to run the mstest via command line when i'm using /resultsfile:"file_name.trx" on the second time it will not run because the file is already exist.

How can i use the same file-name and simply override the existent trx file.

Comment: You should add a tag for whatever OS mstest works with. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach I've used is to add logic into my build script to delete the file before the test is run.

```
<Delete Files="file_name.trx" Condition="Exists('file_name.trx')"/>
```